# Убрать фон кнопки в Swing

Tags: java, swing

Как убрать фон кнопки так, чтобы осталось только одно изображение? Сама иконка 16x16

[image: Кнопка]

```
JButton saveButton = new JButton();
    saveButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Text Editor/task/res/SaveIcon.png"));
    saveButton.setName("SaveButton");
    topPanel.add(saveButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался.

```
    saveButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    saveButton.setFocusPainted(false); saveButton.setOpaque(false);
    saveButton.setMargin(new Insets(1,1,1,1));
    saveButton.addActionListener(new SaveButton());
```